# Is there an elegant alternative to filtering these results without using lots of if statements?

Tags: python, filtering

I am performing some simulations in python that generates 1000 results. Each result has multiple properties such as risk, cost etc

I now want to identify results that meeting certain criteria, for example:

```
Factor 1, cost should be between 10 and 20
Factor 2, risk should be between 0 and 5
Factor 3...
Factor 4...
....
```

Currently I am using a series of nested if statements to do this. As more factors are added the nesting gets messy. Is there an elegant alternative for filtering given certain criteria?

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: Also, you know about pythons `filter` function?

Comment: Each of the 1000 results is a Portfolio class, and each Portfolio has a number of methods to access Total_Assets, Total_Risk, Total_Cost etc. And it is the return values from these methods that I am actually checking against the factors to do the filtering

Comment: I am not familiar with python's filter function. I'll look into it thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions that depend on your data and preferred code style.  E.g.:

```
>>> conditions = (lambda x: 10 < x.cost < 20, lambda x: 0 < x.risk < 10)
>>> filter(lambda x: all(cond(x) for cond in conditions), result)
```

Or just:

```
>>> conditions = lambda x: 10 < x.cost < 20 and 0 < x.risk < 10
>>> filter(conditions, result)
```

Or:

```
>>> [r for r in result if 10 < r.cost < 20 and 0 < r.risk < 10]
```